# Rails 4 / JS / HTML Unable to add a drop down menu so it creates a filter for a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Trying to figure out how to add a dropdown menu so it creates a filter for my html table which features listings of products. Using my non existant Javascript skills & google i have come across this piece of interesting code

http://www.bclittleleague.bc.ca/Baseball/Javascript/TableFilter_EN/examples_EN.htm#tbl2  (table2)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
    var table2_Props =  {                   
                    col_0: "select",
                    col_5: "none",
                    display_all_text: " [ Show all ] ",
                    sort_select: true
                };
    setFilterGrid( "table2",table2_Props );
//]]>
</script>
```

I have added this to my listing.js.coffee file

```
//<![CDATA[ 
    var table2_Props =  {                   
                    col_0: "select",
                    col_5: "none",
                    display_all_text: " [ Show all ] ",
                    sort_select: true
                };
    setFilterGrid( "table2",table2_Props );
//]]>
```

listings.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing listings</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= listing.name %></td>
        <td><%= listing.description %></td>
        <td><%= listing.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', listing %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', listing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path %>
```

but when i compile i get `ExecJS::RuntimeError in Listings#index. SyntaxError: [stdin]:2:2: reserved word "var" in Desktop/Rails/fooddemo/app/assets/javascripts/listings.js.coffee)`

Fooddemo
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> **<-error**
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Comment: `listing.js.coffee` should contain CoffeeScript, not JavaScript. `listing.js` OTOH would contain JavaScript.

Comment: ok thanks do you think this would be better if i used jQuery/datatables gem?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about the gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mu is correct the issue is within the listing.js.coffee file. `var` causes this error after coffeescript.

There are two ways to resolve:

1) convert your code to coffeescript. There is a useful converter at http://js2coffee.org/ which gives the following:

> ```
> table2_Props =
>   col_0: "select"
>   col_5: "none"
>   display_all_text: " [ Show all ] "
>   sort_select: true
>
> setFilterGrid "table2", table2_Props
> ```

If you paste that in, you need to be careful that all spacing is maintained correctly.

2) change the file name to listing.js and it will treat the code as plain javascript.